# HTML Tag Formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone please tell me how to auto-format (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D) HTML tags like this:

```
<label id="myLabelId">Hello</label>
```

to this format:

```
<label id="myLabelId">
    Hello
</label>
```

in Visual Studio 2012. I think it would be some setting in Tools -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting. I am just not sure, what settings to change.

Thanks

Harit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+K then Ctrl+D, will format the current document.

Ctrl+K then Ctrl+F, will format the selected text.

or custom formatting for the text (HTML) editor, got to:

Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting -> Tag Specific Options (Button)
-> Client HTML Tags -> a -> Set Line breaks dropdown to Before and after

Do this for all the tags you want formatted differently.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for label (which you have to add first btw)